# Google Analytics tracking code not recognising 2 params?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have the following variables set up to pass to the google analytics tracking code but for some reason analytics doesn't recognise them, I have a feeling it has something to do with the javascript I use to actually retrieve the data attributes? Can anyone help?

JS

```
var video_id = this.getFocussedItem().data('id');
var product_id = ev.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-product-id');
var product_name = ev.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-product-name');

console.log(product_name, product_id);

_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Product Gadget', 'Product thumbnail click', product_name, product_id]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure product_id is an integer? `_trackEvent` will fail silently if value parameter is a a non-integer.

Comment: Good call, I was passing in a string as the value parameter so wrapped the value in parseInt and now everything is all good, thanks!